# Test for ARM32 compatibility

Tags: arm-processors

I'm trying to programmatically test if a phone supports 32-bit binaries.  The command

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist | grep armeabi
```

seems like it should work.  However, are there other ABI names I need to test for?

(Note: I do know that `abilist` is unavailable prior to Lollipop and that `abi` should be used instead in such a case.)

Comment: See supported ABIs at https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#sa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of current ABIs is available in the [NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#sa). The 32-bit ARM ABI you should look for on modern devices is [armeabi-v7a](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#v7a).